# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - scaffolding not generating any files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, scaffolding

Brand new to ASP.NET - have limited experience with a lot of languages - HTML, CSS, PHP, perl python, shell, powershell - but not with any depth.  Not "new" to coding, just not really any good.

Anyway, I'm trying to do this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-2.1

I managed to generate scaffolding the first time I tried, but now every time I try to generate the scaffolding VS2017 doesn't generate any files.

my class I'm trying to use to generate scaffolding:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace VisitorLog.Models
{
    public class VisitorLog
    { 
    public string VisitorName { get; set; }
    public int FloorNum { get; set; }
    public int OfficeNum { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public DateTime InTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime OutTime { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Is a .NET Core 2.1 Web App (non-MVC) with packages:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design 2.1.2
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.6
```

Anybody know why it wouldn't be generating the pages?  Thanks

Comment: can you currently build the project?    I've noticed in VS2017 that scaffolding fails when the project won't build.

Comment: Yep, it builds fine - which is just viewing the default framework web page, at this point.  I am trying out the tutorial in Code to see if a more hands-on approach will enlighten what the issue is through the IDE.  I thought it might be better for learning what's going on under the hood (it's great that the tutorial is written for both)

Comment: do you get any kind of errors or indications of there being an issue?   Or is it just silently failing?

Comment: Appears to have the hallmarks of being about to work - requires CPU power, the progress bar comes up, says it's finished then no files in pages/Movies.  Using Code is DEFINITELY not any easier, damn there are a lot of issues with nuget and dotnet add package, no continuity.  Makes me long for apt and zypper.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this last comment yesterday...what version of VS2017 are you running?   Looks like there were some confirmed bug(s) by MSFT in scaffolding prior to V15.9.   I'm currently running 15.8.7 and still running into issues too.   I think I am going to upgrade today based on that info.  Most current version as of today (11/28) is 15.9.2.   You may want to look into the version and make sure you are on the latest version.

Comment: Oh great, I'll try that out - thanks.  I've been working with just Code and the command line and that's been good for learning where everything goes instead of having the IDE do all the work for me.